# Set default initial marker on specific point onload: Google Maps Directions Service

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want there to be a marker present when the map loads. Perhaps I could use `DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);` but do not know how to go about this. Using JSON data to plot long and lat but here is the map code.

```
(function(mapDirections, $, undefined) {
    mapDirections.Directions = (function() {

        function _Directions() {
            var map,
                directionsService, directionsDisplay, 
                autoSrc, autoDest, pinA, pinB,

                markerA = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.africanbudgetsafaris.com/images/icons/mm_20_green.png',
                        new google.maps.Size(24, 27),
                        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        new google.maps.Point(12, 27)),     
                markerB = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.africanbudgetsafaris.com/images/icons/mm_20_green.png',
                        new google.maps.Size(24, 28),
                        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        new google.maps.Point(12, 28)), 

                // Caching the Selectors        
                $Selectors = {
                    mapCanvas: jQuery('#map_offices')[0], 
                    dirPanel: jQuery('#directionsPanel'),
                    dirInputs: jQuery('.directionInputs'),
                    dirSrc: jQuery('#dirSource'),
                    dirDst: jQuery('#dirDestination'),
                    getDirBtn: jQuery('#getDirections'),
                    dirSteps: jQuery('#directionSteps'), 
                    paneToggle: jQuery('#paneToggle'), 
                    useGPSBtn: jQuery('#useGPS'), 
                    paneResetBtn: jQuery('#paneReset')
                },

                autoCompleteSetup = function() {
                    autoSrc = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($Selectors.dirSrc[0]);
                    autoDest = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($Selectors.dirDst[0]);
                }, // autoCompleteSetup Ends

                directionsSetup = function() {
                    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        suppressMarkers: true
                    }); 

                    directionsDisplay.setPanel($Selectors.dirSteps[0]);                                         
                }, // direstionsSetup Ends

                trafficSetup = function() {                 
                    // Creating a Custom Control and appending it to the map
                    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div'), 
                        controlUI = document.createElement('div'), 
                        trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();

                    jQuery(controlDiv).addClass('gmap-control-container').addClass('gmnoprint');
                    jQuery(controlUI).text('Traffic').addClass('gmap-control');
                    jQuery(controlDiv).append(controlUI);               

                    // Traffic Btn Click Event    
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
                        if (typeof trafficLayer.getMap() == 'undefined' || trafficLayer.getMap() === null) {
                            jQuery(controlUI).addClass('gmap-control-active');
                            trafficLayer.setMap(map);
                        } else {
                            trafficLayer.setMap(null);
                            jQuery(controlUI).removeClass('gmap-control-active');
                        }
                    });                           
                    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);                               
                }, // trafficSetup Ends


                mapSetup = function() {
                    map = new google.maps.Map($Selectors.mapCanvas, {
                            zoom: 15,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92175976307374, 18.420724868774414),
                            icon: markerA,

                            mapTypeControl: true,
                            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
                                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                            },

                            panControl: true,
                            panControlOptions: {
                                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                            },

                            zoomControl: true,
                            zoomControlOptions: {
                                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                            },

                            scaleControl: true,
                            streetViewControl: true, 
                            overviewMapControl: true,

                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });

                    autoCompleteSetup();
                    directionsSetup();
                    trafficSetup();
                }, // mapSetup Ends 

                directionsRender = function(source, destination) {
                    $Selectors.dirSteps.find('.msg').hide();
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                    var request = {
                        origin: source,
                        destination: destination,
                        provideRouteAlternatives: false, 
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    };      

                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                            var _route = response.routes[0].legs[0]; 

                            pinA = new google.maps.Marker({position: _route.start_location, map: map, icon: markerA}), 
                            pinB = new google.maps.Marker({position: _route.end_location, map: map, icon: markerB});                                                                    
                        }
                    });
                }, // directionsRender Ends

                fetchAddress = function(p) {
                    var Position = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude),  
                        Locater = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    Locater.geocode({'latLng': Position}, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var _r = results[0];
                            $Selectors.dirSrc.val(_r.formatted_address);
                        }
                    });
                }, // fetchAddress Ends

                invokeEvents = function() {
                    // Get Directions
                    $Selectors.getDirBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var src = $Selectors.dirSrc.val(), 
                            dst = $Selectors.dirDst.val();

                        directionsRender(src, dst);
                    });

                    // Reset Btn
                    $Selectors.paneResetBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                        $Selectors.dirSteps.html('');
                        $Selectors.dirSrc.val('');
                        $Selectors.dirDst.val('');

                        if(pinA) pinA.setMap(null);
                        if(pinB) pinB.setMap(null);     

                        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);                 
                    });

                    // Use My Location / Geo Location Btn
                    $Selectors.useGPSBtn.on('click', function(e) {      
                        if (navigator.geolocation) {
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                                fetchAddress(position);
                            }); 
                        }
                    });
                }, //invokeEvents Ends 

                _init = function() {
                    mapSetup();
                    invokeEvents();
                }; // _init Ends

            this.init = function() {
                _init();
                return this; // Refers to: mapDirections.Directions
            }
            return this.init(); // Refers to: mapDirections.Directions.init()
        } // _Directions Ends
        return new _Directions(); // Creating a new object of _Directions rather than a function
    }()); // mapDirections.Directions Ends
})(window.mapDirections = window.mapDirections || {}, jQuery);
```

I need a marker when the map initialises. How?

Comment: Where do you want the [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)?  What does your HTML look like?

Comment: The MarkerImage class is deprecated, you should use the [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some deprecated code with your approach. (depending which version of google maps api v3 you are using).

For instance, MarkerImage:

```
...
markerA = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.africanbudgetsafaris.com/images/icons/mm_20_green.png',
new google.maps.Size(24, 27),
new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(12, 27)),
markerB = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.africanbudgetsafaris.com/images/icons/mm_20_green.png',
new google.maps.Size(24, 28),
new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(12, 28)),
...
```

..is replaced by **[Icon type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#convertingtoicon)**.

From the docs:

> The Icon object literal was added in version 3.10, and replaces
>   MarkerImage from version 3.11 onwards.

Hence, current version of google maps is 3.17 (experimental) and 3.16 (release).

Also **[mapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)** doesn't take property called `icon` at all:

```
...
map = new google.maps.Map($Selectors.mapCanvas, {
                            zoom: 15,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92175976307374, 18.420724868774414),
                            icon: markerA, // <-- not valid
...
```

If you wan't to create a marker (with icon) and show it at map, you just create a marker to the map, and center your map to that location:

```
function initialize() {

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);

   var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
   };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

   // Example marker image
   var markerImage = {
        url: "http://placehold.it/64/ff0000", 
        size: new google.maps.Size(64, 64),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 32)
   };

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatlng,
       map: map,
       title: 'Hello World!',
       icon: markerImage  // How to place icon to marker
   });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

See: **[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/xWR2x/)**

I also recommend that you check the **[google maps api examples page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)** because it is full of useful examples. (Including **[how to place a marker to the map on load](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)**).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to put a marker using your markerImages:

```
var someMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        map: map,
        title: 'Some marker',
        icon: markerA
    });
```

Just call it whenever after map initialization. You even have a sample of this in the posted code.